# PHP Delete all files that contain a given string

Tags: php, regex, caching, unlink

I have a basic cache system setup which saves a file based on the parameters in the url so that if that page gets viewed again it accesses the static file.  eg if my url is

```
http://www.example.com/female/?id=1
```

I have a file located in a cache folder called id=1.html

```
female/cache/id=1.html
```

currently this is cached for a specified amount of time however I want it to always use the cached file unless the page is updated.

So I implemented the below php code.

```
    <?
        unlink('../' . $gender . '/cache/id=' . $_POST['id'] . '.html');
    ?>
```

this works fine however, some times there are additional parameters in my url.  So currently I have the below files in my cache folder

```
    female/cache/id=1.html
    female/cache/id=1&type=2.html
    female/cache/id=1&type=3.html
    female/cache/id=1&type=3&extra=4.html
```

But when I save my content only female/cache/id=1.html is removed.

How would I go about removing any file in this folder with the id=1

Comment: Please don't use short open tags `<? ?>` because it's a **pain** if you moved to an environment where it's disabled by default.

Comment: @HamZa thanks for the tip I hadn't thought about it to much but looking at my code here it is all using <?php but I will make sure I keep it in mind.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use [`glob`](http://php.net/glob):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("female/cache/id=1*.html") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
}
?>
```

Where the asterisk `*` matches all the variations of the filename.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can make the operation more concise using `array_map()`:

```
<?php
array_map('unlink', glob('female/cache/id=1*.html'));
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Be aware that array_map may be slower than a foreach loop:
[Performance of foreach, array_map with lambda and array_map with static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function)

However, this may no longer be the case under PHP 7.x. My results for the accepted answer's benchmark on 7.04:

- **Foreach: 0.096698999404907** // accepted answer's method
- MapClosure: 0.10490107536316
- **MapNamed: 0.073607206344604** // my alternative