# foreach loop through multidimensional array and only echo arrays containing specific value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array stored in `$t_comments` that looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 889
            [1] => First comment
            [2] => 8128912812
            [3] => approved
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 201
            [1] => This is the second comment
            [2] => 333333
            [3] => deleted
        )

    // There is more...
)
```

Currently, I loop through the array like this:

```
foreach($t_comments as $t_comment) {
    echo $t_comment[0]; // id
    echo $t_comment[1]; // comment
    echo $t_comment[2]; // timestamp
    echo $t_comment[3]; // status
}
```

I want to foreach loop through the array and only display arrays that have the value `approved` (as seen above). **How do I do this** when having performance in consideration?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: The closest I could think of was to do an if statement checking each loop if the status is 'approved', but that seems like a bad approach when considering performance.

Comment: Actually I think that the best approach as regards to performance is what @HenrikPetterson suggested. Check these [benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function).

Answer (score 1):

The best possible solution is to not have to check in the first place.

If you controlled the source that inflate the $t_comment array you could make it not send the comments that are not approved.

For example, if you have something like:

```
$t_comments = get_comments
```

You could use something like:

```
$t_comments = get_approved_comments
```

But if you can't then you will have to iterate through each array looking for what you want.

To do so you have to put an "if" inside your foreach to check your variable content so you know it's approved and then you know you can show it, echoing it.

Example:

```
foreach($t_comments as $t_comment) {
    if($t_comment[3]=="approved"){
          echo $t_comment[0];
          echo $t_comment[1];
          echo $t_comment[2];
          echo $t_comment[3]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? You are using terms I am yet to learn :)

Comment: This is what I wrote in my comment to my question, but it doesn't seem like the best approach when considering performance...

Comment: Usually I would have a field with a status so I could check it instead of having a comment saying approved.

Comment: Is this the only and best approach when considering performance?

Comment: Well, if you controlled your source, you could make it not to send the comments that are not approved in first place so you don't need to check it.

Comment: THAT is exactly the approach I am looking for, could you kindly update your answer explaining how I could do that, or at least give me some hints and I can figure out the rest.