# Convert all POST variables to htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, post

In my PHP application, I have lots of places where I get POST data and have to convert it to htmlspecialchars, so I find myself having to specify and convert each element in $_POST individually. Here's an example:

```
$tusername=htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$tfname=htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$tlname=htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$temail=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$tskill=htmlspecialchars($_POST['skillsearchpriv'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

This can get tedious, especially when you have over +10 $_POST variables for multiple forms.

Is there away of converting all POST variables to htmlspecialchars at once?

Something like `$_POST=htmlspecialchars($_POST[allkeys], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');`?

Comment: Did you find that any of these answers was helpful? You have neither accepted any of them, nor made any comment as feedback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to go is `array_map()`, which provides you a means of applying a particular function call (referred to as a `callback`) to each element of an array.

```
 $newpost = array_map ( 'htmlspecialchars' , $_POST );
```

Then you can get `$newpost['firstname']`, etc

Answer (score 3):

A simple `foreach` loop should suffice.

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
}

?>
```

**Reading Material**

[Performance of foreach, array_map with lambda and array_map with static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function)

Comment: Looking through the "Reading Material", I get the impression that the performance differences might have come from `xdebug` itself. Didn't you notice that?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo it was more of a general read as I found it interesting and it was somewhat related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Something like $_POST=htmlspecialchars($_POST[allkeys], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');?

You shouldn't do this. You use post data also for other thing, and you should use `htmlspecialchars` **only** for escape data in your html page.

What you want is to use some template engine like [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), that has automatic escaping enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) 
e.g.

```
function xss_protect(&$item) {
  $item = htmlspecialchars($item);
}
array_walk($_POST, 'xss_protect');
```