# Populate option tags using three values from each row of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-select

I want to populate option tags from my array:

```
$array = [
    [
        "id" => "64",
        "name" => "Freddy",
        "firstname" => "Lang"
    ],
    [
        "id" => "77",
        "name" => "Samual",
        "firstname" => "Johnson"
    ]
];
```

I tried with:

```
$id = array_column($array, 'id');
$firstname = array_column($array, 'firstname');
$name = array_column($array, 'name');
echo "<select>";
  echo implode('<option value ="'.$id.'"'>'.$firstname.' '.$name.'</option>); 
echo "</select>";
```

But I get a blank page as result.

I expect:

```
<option "64">Freddy Lang</option>
<option "77">Samual Johnson</option>
```

Comment: you may use `foreach` to do this, why you want to do this this way?

Comment: Your `implode()` function doesn't look correct, you need glue and an array.

Comment: @hassan I thought foreach is taking more loading time

Comment: @Jarla absolutely

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I tested it. I do not have a blank page now. But my select box is empty.

Comment: @Jarla: it's totally false, `foreach` is faster than all array functions.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I get the error implode(): Invalid arguments passed;

Comment: implode takes an array as a second parameter!

Comment: it is not the prober way to do this using implode in this context

Comment: @hassan Ah ok, I understand, so is it possible to put `<option>` before and `</option>` after the array?

Comment: @hassan what else would you suggest

Comment: using implode, no;

Comment: foreach is faster than array_{map,walk} http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_map` to transform the input array into the html code for a `<option>`  then `implode` all, using only one statement:

```
echo "<select>" . implode('', array_map(function($row) { 
     return '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'. $row['firstname'] .' '. $row['name'].'</option>';
 }, $array )) . "</select>";
```

Comment: Is this a better way than using foreach?

Comment: I like more the functional approach but it really depends on your taste.

Comment: Are there any advantages or disadvantages or is it just a matter of taste?

Comment: My solution has only one statement.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU So faster if there is a lot of data

Answer (score 2):

using implode is not the prober way in this context:

using foreach:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option value ="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['firstname'].' '.$value['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Ok, I use foreach if this is the best way :)

Comment: I don't agree with your statement: `using implode is not the proper way in this context:`; `implode` is fine if used the right way. Anyway, your solution is OK :)

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU greeting, as i said it is not the prober way in **this context**, and don't meant that is implode can not do task like this -*even as a work-around*-

Comment: for example, your solution is pretty cool, but if the `id` element is was the array key ? array map it self does not return the array key, and you will need to use array_walk for example, while you can easily handle this using foreach

Answer (score 0):

Your array data is perfectly prepared for iterated calls of `vsprintf()` to elegantly and clearly populate the option tag strings.  This eliminates messy, hard-to-maintain code that leverages concatenation and/or interpolation to form strings with multiple variables.

I absolutely would implode these strings with a newline character in a professional script.  There is nothing unprofessional about using a `foreach()` loop to make these `vsprintf()` calls either.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VSEVG))

```
echo implode(
         "\n",
         array_map(
             fn($row) => vsprintf(
                 '<option "%d">%s %s</option>',
                 $row
             ),
             $array
         )
     );
```

For more explicit control of the elements used in the option tag string, use `sprintf()` and hardcode the element keys. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kA841))

```
echo implode(
         "\n",
         array_map(
             fn($row) => sprintf(
                 '<option "%d">%s %s</option>',
                 $row['id'],
                 $row['name'],
                 $row['firstname']
             ),
             $array
         )
     );
```

Output (from either snippet):

```
<option "64">Freddy Lang</option>
<option "77">Samual Johnson</option>
```