# What is the best (cheapest) way to CamelCase complex input strings?

Tags: php, regex, php-7, camelcasing, php-7.1

I have a large number of real-time incoming phrases which need to be transofrmed to `alpha only - CamelCase`  by word and split point.

That's what I came up so far, but is there any cheaper and faster way to perform that task?

```php
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump(string $string): string {
  $string = preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/u", ' ', $string);
  $string = ucwords($string);
  $camelCase = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
  return $camelCase;
}

// $expected = "ThQuCkBrWnFXJumpsVRThLZyDG";
$string = " Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ";
$is = FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump($string);
```

#### Results:

**Sentences:** `100000000`
**Total time:** `40.844197034836 seconds`
**average:** `0.000000408`

Comment: Please stop using so much bold.

Comment: @Daedalus whats you problem with bold in right place?

Comment: fair enough, not my intention to irritate anybody. Thought to bring attention to obstacles I'm facing without anybody needing to read to much, but will keep it in mind next time.

Comment: You do 0.2 billion regex based replaces in about 41 seconds - that's not good enough?

Comment: You don't say why the current performance is an issue: you might need to frame the situation a bit more to contextualise it. We might be looking at the wrong part of the problem. As @RobinMackenzie alludes to... this *might* be a case of premature optimisation to me. Do you actually have a business-related problem you're trying to solve? ie: "this thing is taking too long, and we're losing money as a result". That's when one might need to start micro-optimising. Not saying you *don't* have a legit case; but yer not explaining it.

Comment: Since you want to deal with unicode strings, you can't use functions like `ucwords` or `ucfirst` that are not unicode aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is quite efficient. You can still improve with a few tweaks:

- Provide the delimiter to `ucwords` so it does not have to look for `\t`, `\n`, etc, which will not be in your string any way after the first step. On average this gives 1% improvement;
- You can perform the last step with a non-regex replace on a space. This gives up to 20% improvement.

Code:

```
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump(string $string): string {
    $string = preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/u", ' ', $string);
    $string = ucwords($string, ' ');
    $camelCase = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
    return $camelCase;
}
```

See the timings for the original and improved version on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/MCCBB65319).

Note: As you used `ucwords`, your code cannot be used reliably for unicode strings in general. To cover for that you would need to use a function like [`mb_convert_case`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php):

```
$string = mb_convert_case($string,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
```

... but this has a performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

Bench-marked against 3 alternatives, I believe your method is the fastest. Here's the results from 100,000 iterations:

```
array(4) {
  ["Test1"]=>
  float(0.23144102096558)
  ["Test2"]=>
  float(0.41140103340149)
  ["Test3"]=>
  float(0.31215810775757)
  ["Test4"]=>
  float(0.98423790931702)
}
```

Where `Test1` is yours, `Test2` and `Test3` are mine, and `Test4` is from @RizwanMTuman's answer (with a fix).

I thought using `preg_split` may give you an opportunity to optimise. In this function, only 1 regex is used and returns an array of only the alpha items to which you then apply `ucfirst` to:

```
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_2(string $string): string {
    return implode('', array_map(function($word) {
        return ucfirst($word);
    }, preg_split("/[^[:alpha:]]/", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
}
```

This can be further optimised by using `foreach` instead of `array_map` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function)):

```
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_3(string $string): string {
    $validItems = preg_split("/[^[:alpha:]]/u", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $result = '';
    foreach($validItems as $item) {
        $result .= ucfirst($item);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This leads me to speculate that 2 regexes and 1 `ucwords` is faster than 1 regex and multiple `ucfirst`s.

Full test script:

```
<?php

// yours
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_1(string $string): string {
  $string = preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/u", ' ', $string);
  $string = ucwords($string);
  $camelCase = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
  return $camelCase;
}

// mine v1
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_2(string $string): string {
    return implode('', array_map(function($word) {
        return ucfirst($word);
    }, preg_split("/[^[:alpha:]]/", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
}

// mine v2
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_3(string $string): string {
    $validItems = preg_split("/[^[:alpha:]]/u", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $result = '';
    foreach($validItems as $item) {
        $result .= ucfirst($item);
    }
    return $result;
}

// Rizwan with a fix
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_4(string $string): string {
    $re = '/(?:\b|\d+)([a-z])|[\d+ +!.@]/';
    $result = preg_replace_callback($re,function ($matches) {
        return (isset($matches[1]) ? strtoupper($matches[1]) : '');
    },$string);
    return $result;
}


// $expected = "ThQuCkBrWnFXJumpsVRThLZyDG";
$test1 = 0;
$test2 = 0;
$test3 = 0;
$test4 = 0;

$loops = 100000;

$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$loops; $i++) {
    $string = " Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ";
    $is = FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_1($string);
    if($loops==1) echo $is."\n";
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$test1 = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$loops; $i++) {
    $string = " Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ";
    $is = FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_2($string);
    if($loops==1) echo $is."\n";
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$test2 = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$loops; $i++) {
    $string = " Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ";
    $is = FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_3($string);
    if($loops==1) echo $is."\n";
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$test3 = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$loops; $i++) {
    $string = " Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ";
    $is = FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHump_4($string);
    if($loops==1) echo $is."\n";
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$test4 = $time_end - $time_start;

var_dump(array('Test1'=>$test1, 'Test2'=>$test2, 'Test3'=>$test3, 'Test4'=>$test4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(?:\b|\d+)([a-z])|[\d+ +!.@]
```

> UPDTAE ( [Run it here](http://ideone.com/19IQLq) )

Well the idea above is to show you how the thing should be working in regex:

The following is a php implementation of the above regex. You may compare it with yours as this enables the operation to be done by single replace operation:

```
<?php

$re = '/(?:\b|\d+)([a-z])|[\d+ +!.@]/';
$str = 'Th3 qu!ck br0wn f0x jumps 0v3r th3 l@zy d0g. ';
$subst=strtoupper('\\1');

$result = preg_replace_callback($re,function ($matches) {
return (isset($matches[1]) ? strtoupper($matches[1]) : '');
    },$str);

echo $result;

?>
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bskr8N/1)

Comment: OP is asking in relation to speed. Also isn't `\U` a [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) specific thing?

Comment: Downvoting & flagging as it doesn't answer the question. The regex dialect used is not valid in PHP, and clearly wasn't tested in PHP.

Comment: @AdamCameron I have updated the answer.. don't you think it was premature to do flagging an answer which didn't give you a php implementation rather generic idea of the solution ?

Comment: You get a bunch of `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1` errors as well as the correct output with that. You might try `return (isset($matches[1]) ? strtoupper($matches[1]) : '');`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie you are absolutely right .. updated ... thanks mate

Comment: @rizwan: I flagged it as "not an answer, but could be with some revision". You seem to actually agree. Not sure what the problem is. Your update is now good, and I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: @Adam Cameron, relax mate,  I aint that serious either :) ..  but I never got a flag thus not quite clear about flagging ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking to improve performances of a code, you need first to build a code that works. Actually you are trying to build a code that handles utf8 encoded strings (since you added the u modifier to your pattern); but with the string: `liberté égalité fraternité` your code returns `Liberté égalité Fraternité` instead of `Liberté Égalité Fraternité` because `ucwords` (or `ucfirst`) are not able to deal with [multibyte characters](http://utf8-chartable.de/).

After trying different approaches (with `preg_split` and `preg_replace_callback`), it seems that this `preg_match_all` version is the fastest:

```
function FoxJourneyLikeACamelsHumpUPMA(string $string): string {
    preg_match_all('~\pL+~u', $string, $m);
    foreach ($m[0] as &$v) {
        $v = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($v, 0, 1)) . mb_strtolower(mb_substr($v, 1));
    }
    return implode('', $m[0]);
}
```

Obviously, it's slower than your initial code, but we can't really compare these different codes since yours doesn't work.