# PHP - how count percent of each value in array

Tags: php

In PHP, I have an array:

```
$a = array(10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
```

I want to add 5% to each element of the array `$a`, so that it looks like this:

```
$a = array(10.5, 15.75, 21, 26.25, 31.5);
```

I do not want to use `foreach`.

Comment: You could use array_map. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
$a = array(10, 15, 20, 25, 30);;

$output = array_map(function($val) { return $val + ($val*5/100); }, $a);

print_r($output);

    ?>
```

Output :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10.5
    [1] => 15.75
    [2] => 21
    [3] => 26.25
    [4] => 31.5
)
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$a = array(10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
$a = array_map(function($value) { return $value * 1.05; }, $a);
```

Gives: `array(10.5, 15.75, 21, 26.25, 31.5);`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it was answered first without any unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The array_map function should be the solution you are looking for ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php)).

I guess you'll have to create a function like this :

```
function fivePercent($n)
{
    return($n * 1.05);
}
```

And use array_map to call it on each number in your array :

```
$b = array_map("fivePercent", $a);
```

edit : [Working code here.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33cae6d98552d4d0603502a71817b54d8b71b874)

edit 2 : According to the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function), it is faster to use foreach, but since you asked not to use it, calling a named function is much faster than writing the function in the array_map call. Anyway, it doesn't matter with small arrays, just consider this when you have a lot of numbers to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your custom function,

```
$arr = array_map(function($i){
        return $i+($i*0.05);
    }, $arr);
    print_r($arr);
```

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fd0706be30558deaa9fc390e517ac18a8383812).

**array_map** — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction($num)
{
  return($num + ($num * .05));
}

$a=array(10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
print_r(array_map("myfunction",$a));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 10.5 [1] => 15.75 [2] => 21 [3] => 26.25 [4] => 31.5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array_map function of php

```
$a = array(10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
$arrReturn = array_map("increment", $a);
print_r($arrReturn);

function increment($n){
    $return = $n + ($n * .5);
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, a language construct can be used to loop the array and an as proven by several other answers `array_map()` will do the job, but when you want to apply a user function to every element in an array, that is what `array_walk()` is designed for.  The values are "modified by reference" as they are iterated instead of creating a whole new array then overwriting the old data with the new returned array.

Use the [Mulitplication Assignment Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) to apply the 5% boost to each value encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4q05O))

```
function fivePercentIncrease(&$value) {
    $value *= 1.05;
}

$a = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

array_walk($a, 'fivePercentIncrease');

var_export($a);
```

Or via an anonymous function: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NuDT2))

```
$a = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

array_walk($a, function(&$value) { $value *= 1.05; });

var_export($a);
```

Or via an anonymous function using PHP7.4's arrow function syntax: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2r3EU))

```
$a = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];

array_walk($a, fn(&$value) => $value *= 1.05);

var_export($a);
```