# Apply preg_match to all the elements of array

Tags: php

How to apply preg_match on each element of an array

```
$array = [abc,def,ghi];
```

Right now i am doing this

```
foreach($array as $one_element){   
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_. -]{1,23}$/",$one_element)){
        die("One of element  name is not valid");
    }
}
```

Is there any easier and faster way to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with `array_map`:

```
array_map(
    function($elem) {
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_. -]{1,23}$/', $elem)){
            die("One of element  name is not valid");
        }
    },
    $array
);
```

Comment: Thanks ! looks great

Comment: 8 lines instead 5. Great!

Comment: @u_mulder One line: `array_map(
    function($elem) {
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_. -]{1,23}$/', $value)){
            die("One of element  name is not valid");
        }
    },
    $array
);` :-)

Comment: isn't it faster @u_mulder .

Comment: Faster then what?

Comment: Than using foreach @u_mulder

Comment: You will be shocked, but `array_map` uses iteration __too__ only under the hood, so I don't see real profit here. And with 3 elements in array you won't win anything.

Comment: @beginner Not really. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function The most expensive call is the `preg_match`, not the iteration itself

Comment: @u_mulder I may have more than 3 elements, maybe 40 . anyway i am using array_map , it can not be slower than foreach .

Comment: @AlexTartan, Thanks , :)

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks , i switched back to foreach.