# How to format an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array with the following format.
I have used array_chunk function to format like the following array.

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [CGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CGST (6%)] => 6.0000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SGST (6%)] => 6.0000
            )

    )
)
```

All I need my array to be displayed in the following format

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [SGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000
        [CGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000

    )

[1] => Array
    (
       [CGST (6%)] => 6.0000
       [SGST (6%)] => 6.0000

    )
)
```

Help to create such format.Thanks

Comment: Key in the array are dynamic from foreach loop like 
`foreach($arr as $key=>$value)`
then `array($key => $value)` is the printed array.

Comment: Or in this simple situation use array_map

Comment: how to use array_map in this situation. Can you solve this using array_map for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try combination of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

To know more about used function check function doc on php.net

```
<?php
$array = array (
    '0' => array
    (
        '0' => array
        (
            'SGST (2.5%)' => '2.5000'
        ),

        '1' => array
        (
            'CGST (2.5%)' => '2.5000'
        )

    ),

    '1' => array
    (
        '0' => array
        (
            'CGST (6%)' => '6.0000'
        ),

        '1' => array
        (
            'SGST (6%)' => '6.0000'
        )

    )
);

echo '<pre>';
$processed = array_map(function($a) {  return array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array()); }, $array);
print_r($processed);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000
            [CGST (2.5%)] => 2.5000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CGST (6%)] => 6.0000
            [SGST (6%)] => 6.0000
        )

)
```

Comment: array_map is too slow. Just use foreach with push ;) See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function

Comment: why down vote? I posted the answer for the question. And I strongly believe there is no constraints for performance mentioned in question. is so?