# How to search in arrays with stdClass?

Tags: php

I have array with stdClasses:

```
$a = new \stdClass();
$a->name = "aaa";
$a->type = "1";

$b = new \stdClass();
$b->name = "bbb";
$b->type = "2";

$c = new \stdClass();
$c->name = "ccc";
$c->type = "1";

$array = array($a, $b, $c);

$count = 0;

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if ($arr->type == 1) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Is better way to count types with value 1 than foreach? I would like counting many values so foreach is uncomfortable.

Maybe array_search or array_map?

Comment: what you are using is best in your requirement already

Comment: you should read it also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function/26527704#26527704

Comment: Have you checked that foreach is actually slow? This sounds a lot like premature optimization. At some place in your code there will be a full iteration of the data, moving that bit, would just hide the fact not prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **array_filter**:

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.array-filter.php

example:

```
$a = new \stdClass();
$a->name = "aaa";
$a->type = "1";

$b = new \stdClass();
$b->name = "bbb";
$b->type = "2";

$c = new \stdClass();
$c->name = "ccc";
$c->type = "1";

$array = array($a, $b, $c);

$count = count(array_filter($array, function($d){
     return $d->type === "1";
}));
```

Comment: Have you checked that this is any faster than simple foreach?

Comment: Yep, it seems that there isn't so much difference between those. I was reading this when you've asked the above question: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/why-array-maparray-filter-over-foreach

Comment: And here I found some benchmarks: http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/