# PHP - The best way to change numeric values into words in an array

Tags: php, arrays, text, numbers

I have a simple array along the lines of [2,4,7,8] and I want to change the entries into the textual equivalents eg ["two","four","seven","eight"].

I know how to convert individual numbers using the NumberFormatter class but is there a good way of doing this with an array of numbers?

Comment: See [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Comment: "Best" is pretty subjective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way should be to use `array_map` with `NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT`

```
$nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$arr = array_map(function($v) use ($nf) {
    return $nf->format($v);
}, $arr);
print_r($arr); // Array ( [0] => two [1] => four [2] => seven [3] => eight )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a foreach

```
$numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
   $array[$key] = $numberFormatter->format($value);
}
```

Performance comparison :

[Stackoverflow - Performance of foreach, array_map with lambda and array_map with static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function)

Comment: Wouldnt `$array[$key] = $numberFormatter->format($value);` be simpler as you actually have the value in a variable

Comment: Yep, I made a mistake

Comment: So fix it, and maybe the last downvote will get removed. None of them were mine by the way

Comment: **Performance:** It really depends on how you bench marked it. Did you tried running this code? https://pastebin.com/vjXaytvg There is a very small difference. I don't think people would actually care about it.