# How can i match 2 arrays and attach prefix to matching values?

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays:

```
a1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
a2 = 1,3,5,7
```

I want to be able to compare both arrays where they match, combine them without duplicates and then attach a prefix or letter to the matching values.

expected result:

```
a3 - match1,2,match3,4,match5,6,match7,8
```

I have looked at `array_intersect()`, but I'm not sure how I would use it in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one for https://adventofcode.com !

This is probably not the most efficient solution performance- or memory-wise, but it should do the trick.

```
$a1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$a2 = [1,3,5];
$result = [];

foreach($a1 as $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $a2)) {
        $result[] = 'match' . $item;   
    } else {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}
```

See it in action here: https://3v4l.org/PlTIZ

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i was looking for thanks!

Comment: No problem! Please tick as an answer so other people can benefit from it too.

Comment: Good self-explanatory solution, however, make use of [pre-built PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). No need to loop through arrays all the time, sure you'll find some good functions to replace foreach loops in the manual for future reference.

Comment: @Jaquarh I did this on purpose, as I both find it easier to read and the `array` functions are a lot slower than `foreach`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function

Comment: That is because `array_map` in this case, which your referring to, replaces the array with new values each time, hence `return`. Building a new array and pushing values in within a loop, in this case **will** be slower. In the case of the question you linked, `array_map` is not needed since the value **does not** change, thus `foreach` will have better performance. My comment wasn't meant to offend you, only, for future reference, point you in the direction of not **always** using `foreach`.

Comment: I certaibly wasn't offended! Actually some very good advice and tips, thanks! I can certainly put this to good use

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve this with better performance and maintainable code.

> [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/cXs9C).

```
$arr_one = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr_two = [1,3,5];

$new_arr = array_map(function($arg) use ($arr_two) {
    return in_array($arg, $arr_two) ? "prefix_{$arg}" : $arg;
}, $arr_one);
```

> Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "prefix_1"
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  string(8) "prefix_3"
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  string(8) "prefix_5"
}
```

> References

- [array_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) → pre-built methods.
- [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator-in-php-as-a-shorthand-for-if-else) → ? :

Comment: Please note that the performance is *not* better with the array functions (often it's actually a lot worse), and the maintainability is pretty subjective. I needed to read your code multiple times before I got what was up. Even though, good answer and good alternative.

Comment: In this case, `array_map()` has achieved better performance. And in multiple other cases, like [this](https://3v4l.org/CAGEE) proves my point about utilising the tools PHP already has before looping through everything @Loek