# Find elements with empty value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, is-empty

I have an array like the below:

```
$arrays = [
    'a' => [
        'name' => "Name 1",
        'age' => "99",
        'add' => ""
    ],
    'b' => [
        'name' => "Name 2",
        'age' => "99",
        'add' => "Add2"
    ],
    'c' => [
        'name' => "Name 3",
        'age' => "99",
        'add' => "Add3"
    ],
    'd' => [
        'name' => "",
        'age' => "",
        'add' => "Add4"
    ]
];
```

I want to get a result like:

```
$res = [
    'a' => ['add'],
    'd' => ['name','age']
];
```

I have tried with the below code, but it returns 1.

```
$status = array_walk_recursive($arrays, function($v, $k) {
    global $output;
    if (empty($v) && $v !== 0)
        $output[$k] = $v;
});
```

I want to do it without using any loops because my real input array is very large and I am concerned with performance.

Comment: Is the array always going to be in the format you show in the question.

Comment: yes.. Format will be same..as like this

Comment: You can't iterate over array without a loop. So, in `array_walk_recursive` there's a loop __too__, but it is hidden ubder the hood.

Comment: I know array walk recursive, which is a loop but this loop is  faster than php custom loop as i know. This is a sample array, but my real array is very big. Thats why i dont wanna use any custom loop like foreach.

Comment: Not sure how up to date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function is, but it seems to contradict your assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always of a fixed depth, you can map the existing values to the keys of all empty items:

```
$output = array_map(function($row) {
    return array_keys(array_filter($row, function ($e) {
        return empty($e) && $e !== 0;
    }));
}, $arrays);
```

The outer function runs for each "row", the value of which is then converted into a list of all keys with empty values (excluding zeroes, as in the question).

This will keep the outer keys B & C as empty arrays, so if you want them to be removed as well then run another iteration of `array_filter` over the result:

```
$output = array_filter($output)
```

See https://3v4l.org/c23ZB

As mentioned in the comments, there are still several loops going on here, they're just not as visible in the code. A regular `foreach` loop might end up being a lot easier to read, and possibly perform faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next combination of [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) & [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
    $result = [];

    array_walk(
        $arrays,
        function($el, $key) use(&$result) {
            $empty = array_filter($el, function($el){return $el == "";});
            $empty_keys = array_keys($empty);
            if (count($empty_keys)) $result[$key] = $empty_keys;
        }
    );
```

Try it [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=3b32731a6c4eba5cf9aaf0d5c7e087dd&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have big array with at least 1 lac+ data. which one is better, custom loop or using built-in function? Someone suggested to use custom loop and some other suggested for built-in function, though I prefer built-in function for better performance. Any suggestion regarding this issue?

Comment: You can find lot of articles about performance `foreach` vs `array_walk` and in most cases `foreach` is bit a faster when `array_walk`. You can try it on your own datasample and post results here

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to achieve your desired output.

```
$result = [];
 foreach($arrays as $key => $value) {
     $empty_arr = array_filter($value, function ($ele) {
         return empty($ele);
     });
      $empty_arr_keys = array_keys($empty_arr);
      if(!empty($empty_arr_keys)) $result[$key] = $empty_arr_keys;        
  }
        
 print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

@iainn's answer can be sharpened up by calling `!strlen()` on the deep values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/K7jtH))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        array_map(
            fn($row) => array_keys(
                array_filter(
                    $row,
                    fn($v) => !strlen($v)
                )
            ),
            $array
        )
    )
);
```

But you will end up making fewer iterations and writing cleaner, more intuitive/readable code if you use classic loops.  This is how I would write it in my own project:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cgJKv))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $rowKey => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if (!strlen($value)) {
            $result[$rowKey][] = $key;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```