# Laravel database insert with combining array and string

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I should insert an array such as `$attendanceList = [18354012,18354013,18354014,18354015]` and `$present = "FALSE"` and same for all item of `$attendanceList`. As you see `$attendanceList` is array but `$present` is `String`.

When I insert like `DB::table("attendance")->insert(["id"=>$attendanceList,"present"=>"FALSE"])` returns error.

What should I do? Pairing all item of `$attendanceList` and `$present` or there are another ways?

**Note:** I don't want to use loop if it is possible.

Comment: Are you trying to insert four rows? Or one row with four values in a single column?

Comment: @AlexHowansky second one, I try to insert four rows with same `$present` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare array from your data and do bulk insert in one query:

```
<?php
$attendanceList = [18354012,18354013,18354014,18354015];
$present = "FALSE";

$insertData = array_map(
    fn($el)=>['id'=>$el, 'present'=>$present],
    $attendanceList
);

$db::table("attendance")->insert($insertData);
```

[Test Laravel DB insert online](https://phpize.online/sql/mariadb/d3940017e5263c46f9bd248a6945c5f1/php/php81/79a4aa2ddfa2c25b6e2d4018b330ab29/)

Comment: I think that is better as syntax than a loop but come to the same thing. Maybe I can put the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144782/performance-of-foreach-array-map-with-lambda-and-array-map-with-static-function).

Comment: @Wtow, I'm not sure but consider eloquent insert with array process bulk insert instead multiple single inserts in loop

Comment: That is good idea to optimize database querry if not possible to optimize loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use a loop. If you want to insert four separate rows, you're going to need one:

```
foreach ($attendanceList as $id) {
    DB::table("attendance")->insert(["id" => $id,"present" => $present]);
}
```

Comment: I have some for loop before this statement, so another for loop will increase complexity. Thank you for your answer, but I prefer to not use if it is possible.

Comment: You can not perform this insert without a loop _somewhere_. Stop micro-optimizing.